# Alternative Ways to Control The Volume Level Of My Mac In OS X?

Tags: macos, audio, sound-volume

Generally to either increase or decrease the volume level of my Mac, I always go to the volume menu bar and adjust the slider accordingly.

I was wondering:

What other ways exist within OS X to adjust volume settings and perhaps give even finer adjustments to the volume level that is produced ?

Comment: I have no more volume on my mac os x vers 10.5.8,maybe the drivers are missing???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Use the volume keys on your keyboard (hold Shift + Option for finer control)
- Go to the Sound pane of System Preferences

Comment: The volume keys are F11 & F12, is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned alternate ways to control the volume. Here is one from the terminal:

```
sudo osascript -e "set Volume 5"
```

You can change to "5" to a higher or lower number to make the volume go up and down in intensity.

```
sudo osascript -e "set Volume 0.1"
```

This will put your volume at super quiet

As @Tortilla stated, for finer control without the terminal, you can hold Shift + Option while using the F11 or F12 keys to adjust the volume by 1/4 (0.25) increments.